# predicting using model.predict() for unlabelled data in tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

i have trained a model and want to it predict on values not used in training, i cant figure out the input format for model.predict() ; my model has 8 input features and i've tried inputting them as lists, DataFrame and dictionary all of which are raising errors

```
feature_columns = []
cement_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("CementComponent")
feature_columns.append(cement_component)

blast_furnace_slag = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("BlastFurnaceSlag")
feature_columns.append(blast_furnace_slag)

fly_ash_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("FlyAshComponent")
feature_columns.append(fly_ash_component)

water_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("WaterComponent")
feature_columns.append(water_component)

superplasticizer_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("SuperplasticizerComponent")
feature_columns.append(superplasticizer_component)

coarse_aggregate_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("CoarseAggregateComponent")
feature_columns.append(coarse_aggregate_component)

fine_aggregate_component = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("FineAggregateComponent")
feature_columns.append(fine_aggregate_component)

age_in_days = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("AgeInDays")
feature_columns.append(age_in_days)

my_feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

def create_model(my_learning_rate, my_feature_layer):
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

  model.add(my_feature_layer)

  
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, 
                                  activation='relu',
                                  kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05),
                                  name='Hidden1'))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units= 3, 
                                  activation='relu', 
                                  kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05),
                                  name='Hidden2'))


  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units= 3, 
                                  activation='relu', 
                                  kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05),
                                  name='Hidden3'))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,  
                                  name='Output'))                              
  
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=my_learning_rate),
                loss="mean_squared_error",
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])

  return model

def train_model(model, dataset, epochs, batch_size, label_name):

  features = {name:np.array(value) for name, value in dataset.items()}
  label = np.array(features.pop(label_name))
  history = model.fit(x=features, y=label, batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs, shuffle=True,validation_split = 0.25)

  epochs = history.epoch
  hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
  rmse = hist["mean_squared_error"]
  valley = hist["val_mean_squared_error"]

  return epochs, rmse, valley  

print("Defined the create_model and train_model functions.")

learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 150
batch_size = 50
label_name = 'Strength'


my_model = create_model(learning_rate, my_feature_layer)

epochs, mse, valley = train_model(my_model, train_df_norm, epochs, batch_size, label_name)
plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, mse, valley)
```

this is the model
now i want to predict on an unlabelled example, but i cant figure out the formatting for .predict
ive tried a couple of different options but its just raising an error

```
prediction = model.predict({'CementComponent':1, 'BlastFurnaceSlag':1, 'FlyAshComponent':1, 'WaterComponent':1, 'SuperplasticizerComponent':1, 'CoarseAggregateComponent':1,'FineAggregateComponent':1,'AgeInDays':1})

print(prediction)
```

On further exploration; i found that `model(data, training = false)` serves the purpose and produced an output;

```
input_data = {'CementComponent':[1], 'BlastFurnaceSlag':[1], 'FlyAshComponent':[1], 'WaterComponent':[1], 'SuperplasticizerComponent':[1], 'CoarseAggregateComponent':[1],'FineAggregateComponent':[1],'AgeInDays':[1]}

my_model(input_data, training=False)
```

I'll try to update here if i find out how to use .predict with this model

Comment: this is the problem i was working on
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/playground-series-s3e9/data?select=train.csv

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `.predict` method, it is necessary to provide an array-like object instead of a dictionary. To utilize your data format for prediction, the labels should be removed, and only the values should be passed as input.

Here's a revised code snippet that demonstrates the appropriate approach:

```py
input_data = {'CementComponent':1, 'BlastFurnaceSlag':1, 'FlyAshComponent':1, 'WaterComponent':1, 'SuperplasticizerComponent':1, 'CoarseAggregateComponent':1,'FineAggregateComponent':1,'AgeInDays':1}
input_values = list(input_data.values())

arr = np.array(input_values)

pred = model.predict(arr)
```

Comment: yeah, i had tried to input arrays like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ;  but then it returns this and i cant make head or tail of it....
https://imgur.com/a/GBwIfRP